# Animating a SwiftUI state change while existing animation is running causes Form to be in an inconsistent state

Tags: animation, swiftui, state, core-animation

I'm trying to implement a text field that updates search results while the user is typing. I've tried this both synchronously (update search results after every keystroke) and asynchronously. Both cause some really weird animation states to occur.

Here is what happens. I first type slowly and backspace slowly and everything works. I then type quickly and backspace quickly.

[image: Demonstration]

I have simplified my View to this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var elements: [Element] = []
  @State var text = ""
  
  var body: some View {
    Form {
      TextField("Text", text: $text)
        .onChange(of: text, perform: { newText in
          withAnimation {
            elements = (0..<newText.count).map { i in
              Element(id: i, value: "\(i)")
            }.shuffled()
        }
        })

      ForEach(elements) { element in
        Text(element.value)
      }
      
      Text("Should have \(elements.count) elements")
    }
  }
}

struct Element: Identifiable {
  var id: Int
  var value: String
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

If you view this in the Preview, the Simulator, or on a device type a few characters into the text field, and then hold backspace, the Form will be in an inconsistent state. Very often even when the text field is empty there is still a Text element with the value "0". I have also seen situations where the "Should have X elements" Text is above the "0" Text element row. After this occurs no further animations will happen when changing the state.

The issue appears to be when I change the `elements` state while an existing animation is running that is animating the previous `elements` state change. If you type in the text field slowly and backspace slowly, the issue does not occur.

This also happens if I use a List instead of a Form. It does not happen if you use a VStack.

EDIT:

In an attempt to remove as many variables as possible I reduced my example down (see below). The issue still persists. If you type in a bunch of characters, then hold backspace, the bottom Text will say "Should have 0 elements" but there are still rows in the list with "old" data. This is happening on iOS 14.4 on an actual device.

I am seeing this message pop up in the console:

> 2021-01-27 12:01:33.231810-0500 Animations[1220:293840] [Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x10410d190, _UIReplicantView) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var text = ""
  
  var body: some View {
    TextField("Text", text: $text)
      .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
      .padding()

    List {
      ForEach(elements) { element in
        Text(element.value)
      }
    }
    .animation(.default)

    Text("Should have \(elements.count) elements")
      .background(Color(.systemRed))
      .padding()
  }
  
  private var elements: [Element] {
    (0..<text.count).map { i in
      Element(id: i, value: "\(i)")
    }.shuffled()
  }
}

struct Element: Identifiable {
  var id: Int
  var value: String
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Provided example works fine with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

Comment: @Asperi really? It doesn't behave like it does in my now attached animated GIF?

Comment: I'm also having inconsistencies when changing state during animation of `Form`. Did you find an explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested this recently and discovered this issue no longer occurs (at least as of iOS 15.3, but probably all of iOS 15).