# SwiftUI Form animation results in inconsistent view state

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When running the below example code in the canvas (Xcode 12.4) or on a device (iOS 14.5) I always end up in an inconsistent UI state if I quickly double click the Edit/Cancel button.

It should just insert or remove a `Section` in the `Form`, but whenever I activate animations it seems to insert the first section "too late":

[image: Inconsistent]
[image: Consistent]

The first image is after a double click and does not reflect the view's state. More specifically the first section is out of sync with the rest of the UI; the first section should not exist. The second image is after a single click and looks as it should.

I get the same result when using `withAnimation` in the `Button`s' action instead of `.animation` on the `Form`.

Minimal example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    
    enum Mode: String { case view, edit }
    
    @State private var mode: Mode = .view
        
    var modeString: String { "We're in \(mode.rawValue) mode" }
    var modeColor: Color { mode == .view ? .green : .red }
    var title: String { mode.rawValue + " mode" }
        
    var body: some View {
                
        let editButton = Button("Edit") { mode = .edit }
        let cancelButton = Button("Cancel") { mode = .view }
                
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                if mode == .edit {
                    Section(header: Text(modeString)) {
                        Text(modeString).foregroundColor(modeColor)
                    }
                }
                
                Section(header: Text(modeString)) {
                    Text(modeString).foregroundColor(modeColor)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: mode == .view ? editButton : cancelButton)
            .navigationBarTitle(title)
            .animation(.default)
        }
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
            TestView()
    }
}
```

Did I do something wrong here?

---

Possibly related question: [Animating a SwiftUI state change while existing animation is running causes Form to be in an inconsistent state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65907630/220820)

Comment: `navigationBarItems` and `navigationBarTitle` are [being deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationbaritems(leading:trailing:)) use `.toolbar` and `navigationTitle`

Comment: @loremipsum Thank you. Is that relevant to the problem at hand? If so, could you elaborate on that? What you suggest I use is not available in iOS 13.

Comment: Could be, if the result from them is inconsistent, that seems to be what you are describing. Do you different results in iOS 13 vs 14 that would be a dead giveaway. If so, use the new methods for iOS 14 and the old ones for iOS 13. Just something to look into.

Comment: @loremipsum There's no inconsistency in the navigation bar title or its items. The only inconsistency is that the first `Section` (inside the `if`) is being inserted as a result of the state being changed once, but doesn't get inserted until after the state has actually changed twice (at which point it should have been removed again). Anyway, I tried using the components you suggested but there is no discernible difference in behavior.